# Replace a conditionally given part of a vector with `NaN`?

Tags: matlab

I would like to replace a part of my vector `A` that is greater than `0.5` with `NaN`. The part of this vector is defined between a certain time frame `x = ( t>=2 & t<5 )`. `t` and `A` have same length.

So far I came up with this:

```
A = [0.1 0.4 0.3 1 0.6 3 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.4 0.8 0.9 0.2 1];
t = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5];
x = (t >= 2 & t < 5);

if A(x) > 0.5
    A = nan;
end
```

However it does not work! I tried various things, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it step by step.

---

## First step - constructing a condition

If you do:

```
A > 0.5
```

you'll get vector with the length of `A` with `1` on the position of elements in `A` that are greater than `0.5`, namely:

```
Columns 1 through 14

0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0

Column 15

1
```

If you do:

```
t >= 2 & t < 5
```

you'll get vector similar to the one above (same length) but this time `1` on the certain position would denote that particular element in vector `t` is in the interval **[ 2, 5 >**. Vector looks like this:

```
Columns 1 through 14

0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

Column 15

0
```

You can combine those two vectors by requiring that both conditions be met with:

```
(A > 0.5) & (t >= 2) & (t < 5)
```

You get vector:

```
Columns 1 through 14

0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0

Column 15

0
```

Notice that ones are on the positions on which there are ones in *both* of the previous two vectors!

---

## Second step - extracting elements from vector

If you do this:

```
A( logical([1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]) )
```

you will notice that only first element is extracted from vector `A`, and you get:

```
0.1000
```

You would extract first two elements with:

```
A( logical([1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]) )
```

and so on.

If you wish to change value of some element in the vector `A`, say first and last element to value `3` you can do it with:

```
A( logical([1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]) ) = 3;
```

---

## Wrapping up (or TLDR)

Extract desired elements from `A` and assign them value of `NaN`:

```
A( (A > 0.5) & (t >= 2) & (t < 5) ) = NaN;
```

Comment: Cool!!! Thanks sooo much!! I didnt thougth of putting both conditions together but indeed it makes sense, totally! Thanks for all the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
A=[0.1 0.4 0.3 1 0.6 3 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.4 0.8 0.9 0.2 1];
t = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5];
x=(t>=2 & t<5);
```

You can simply do the following:

```
A (A > 0.5) = NaN;
```

In GNU Octave, I end up with this output:

```
octave:6> disp(A)
0.10000   0.40000   0.30000   1.00000   0.60000   3.00000   0.30000   0.40000   0.60000   0.80000   0.40000   0.80000   0.90000   0.20000   1.00000
```